# PostgreSQL 9.5: missing FROM-clause entry for table "new"

Tags: postgresql, postgis, plpgsql

I saw many posts like mine, but I didn't manage to find a proper answer to my situation, which should be basic one I presume. I use the extension PostGIS 2.3. Here is my code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.split_cable()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE geometrie geometry;
BEGIN    
geometrie = new.geom;    
create view temp_wire as (
    with brs as (select boite.geom from cablage_pays_gex.boite
    where st_intersects(boite.geom, new.geom) and boite.geom not in (select st_startpoint(st_linemerge(new.geom))) and boite.geom not in (select st_endpoint(st_linemerge(new.geom)))
    )
    select st_dump(st_split(new.geom, brs.geom)) from brs
    );
RETURN new;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

As you can see I have a variable "geometrie" that I am not using, it is because I tried to declare a variable containing the data I want to use, unsuccessfully. The error I get is the one titling my question, and it is pointing to the st_intersects() function (so the first time I try to call the new.geom). What am I doing wrong? And how can I solve this?

**EDIT** : Here is the create table statement on which the trigger is acting :

```
CREATE TABLE public.cable2
(
  id_cable integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('cable2_seq'::regclass),
  geom geometry(MultiLineString,2154),
  CONSTRAINT cable2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_cable)
);
```

Comment: Show us the `create table` statement for the trigger table. But creating a view in a trigger is a **really**, really bad idea - and it will fail after the second DML statement on the underlying table. Which means you can only run a DML statement once and then never again because you'll get an error for every subsequent statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not sure what you mean. I am mostly using third party software QGIS to interact with the db, so I am not using any statement. Do you mean the `create trigger` statement ?

Comment: Then that third party software will stop working because your trigger will fail after the first DML statement against that table. To find out what's wrong with your trigger, we need to see the `create table` statement for the table on which you are defining the trigger.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well it worked fine in other occasions. What  can make the NEW not being recognized?

Comment: I edited my question, is it what you were asking for?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: **Dynamic SQL** is required for the `CREATE VIEW` statement.

In plpgsql,variables are not interpolated in Data Definition queries, like 
`CREATE...` queries.

More generally, the plpgsql [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html) tells it as:

> Parameters will only be substituted in places where a parameter or
>   column reference is syntactically allowed

And in DDL queries, the place where they're allowed is: **nowhere**.

This is why the `new.geom` reference in your query is taken literally, and why transferring it into a temporary variable `geometrie` would not make it work any better.

Dynamic SQL consists basically of building a command string and then executing that string as a statement with `EXECUTE`. That string, once generated, must no longer contain any reference to variables.
More information in the doc: [Executing Dynamic Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Independantly of that, as said in the comments, creating a permanent view every time a row is affected in a table seems completely wrong, at the conceptual level. It's hard to understand why you want to do that in the first place.

Comment: I understand for the bad idea of the view creation. My idea is that I avoid many CTE by first creating a view that I'll call for each INSERT on which my trigger will act, and then dropping it at the end of the transaction. But indeed, it may cause some problem in case of concurrent use amongst other situations. So now I wonder, is it a better idea to create a two level CTE (a CTE inside a CTE) ?

Comment: @GuiOmClair: the answer above is about why there is a syntax error in the trigger. Wether it's a good idea to use nested CTEs looks like a totally different question, which you may ask in a different Q/A slot, but with a quite different text than the trigger code above.